# How to put Raspbian onto an SD without any third party software?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, sd-card, image

I will be getting a Raspberry Pi 3 in the next few weeks and I've been doing a lot of research about it so I know what I need to do to get it working. I want to put Raspbian onto the RPi. I went all around the internet finding ways to do it. The way I found was get an SD card and put Raspbian on it then use "Win32 Disk Imager" to make it work but, I don't want to:

1. Download from SourceForge because they include adware (Source: HowToGeek in [this article](http://www.howtogeek.com/218764/warning-don%E2%80%99t-download-software-from-sourceforge-if-you-can-help-it/) and multiple others that I can not find anymore)
2. Use any third-party programs to do it.

Are there any other built in ways on Windows to do it? As a ***last*** resort I will use Win32 Disk Imager.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure it out myself, for anyone who is having this problem too, here is the solution.

Start Ubuntu in a Virtual machine then follow [this](http://elinux.org/RPi_Easy_SD_Card_Setup#Using_the_Linux_command_line) guide

Comment: Which third party provided the virtual machine software?

Comment: @88weighed Oracle VirtualBox.

Comment: That's still third party software ... Just saying.

Comment: @88weighed I'm not against third party software. I'm against Source Forge software due to their reputation.

Comment: [Etcher](https://etcher.io/) is a good alternative. Not on sourceforge. I believe the Raspberry Pi foundation now recommends it.